# Rails: Determine if attribute on association just changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

We have a `Zoo` model that `has_many` `Animal`s. The `Zoo` model has:

```
after_commit :update_animals

def update_animals
  animals.each(&:do_update_animal)
end
```

The `Animal` model (which `belongs_to` a `Zoo`) in turn has:

```
def do_update_animal
  # here we need to determine whether the `self.zoo.zookeeper` attribute just updated
end
```

Inside of the `Animal#do_update_animal` block, how can we tell if the `zookeeper` attribute on the instance of Zoo associated with the Animal just updated?

---

**NB:** To get this working, I needed to change my `has_many` block on Zoo so as to indicate that Animal is the `inverse_of` Zoo--without that declaration, the dirty API did not work. So inside of Zoo I needed:

```
has_many :animals, inverse_of: :zoo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
# zoo.rb
after_commit :update_animals

def update_animals
  animals.each { |animal|
    animal.do_update_animal
  }
end

# animal.rb
include ZookeeperConcern

# zookeeper_concern.rb
def do_update_animal
  if zoo.zookeeper_previously_changed? # presumably animal belongs_to :zoo, right?
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

This uses the [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) feature.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I don't think it will work in our case. In our real case, `do_update_animal` is actually provided in a concern that's shared on many models, and `do_update_animal` calls a method defined on each `Animal` itself, and it's inside _that_ method that we need to check if the Zoo is dirty. So it would be highly preferable to be able to run a method from the Animal that directly identifies whether the Zoo is dirty/changed, without having to pass the state down through the method chain. Is that possible?

Comment: is it really `Zoo.zookeeper` that you wish to determine if it changed (as you indicate), or is it the particular zoo instance associated with an animal... i.e. `animal.zoo.zookeeper` (seems more likely, but I know nothing about your app!)

Comment: yes you're quite right, we want to know whether the `zookeeper` attribute on the instance of a Zoo associated with the current Animal instance changed. And we want to be able to determine that from inside the Animal instance ideally (I know we can determine that from inside the Zoo and pass it as you've shown, but that is going to make things a little ugly)

Comment: OK, I updated my suggestion. I'm less sure of this update than the original suggestion. Curious to hear what you find.

Comment: I just checked... it seems to work the way you requested... how does it look to you?

Comment: Thanks! It looks good. The real culprit was the absence of a `inverse_of` clause inside the `has_many` block on my Zoo model. Once I added that, I was able to use all the dirty API calls, e.g. `zoo.saved_change_to_zookeeper?`

Comment: interesting, I didn't have `inverse_of` in the small app , 2 models, Zoo (`has_many :animals`), and Animal (`belongs_to :zoo`) that I used to verify this. Rails 7.0.5.

Comment: I technically was accessing the has many relation in a scope, so everytime my Zoo instance updated I didn't access the animals association directly but instead through a scope `animals.current.each do ...`. Possibly that makes the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think this workaround can be a good solution if you can replace the after_commit with around_save and around_destroy

Zoo.rb:

```
around_save :update_animals
around_destroy :update_animals

def update_animals
  zookeeper_changed = zookeeper_changed?
  yield

  animals.each { |animal|
    animal.do_update_animal(zookeeper_changed)
  }
end
```

Animal.rb:

```
def do_update_animal(zookeeper_changed = false)
  return unless zookeeper_changed

  # do something only if zookeeper changed
end
```